# mongodb gridfs in C# new api

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, gridfs

i am new with MongoDB, and i can't find GridFS.
Where can i get GridFS to store files now ?

I can get it this way:

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.MongoDB);
var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
MongoDatabase = server.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.DatabaseName);
MongoDatabase.GridFS...
```

but GetServer() method is obsolete.

if I get database as here:

```
MongoDatabase2 = mongoClient.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.DatabaseName);
MongoDatabase2.GridFS... not working
```

Then i receive IMongoDatabase instead MongoDatabase, and i didnt have GridFS.

Answer (score 1):

Heureka!! Got it! Give me the Nobel prize! :)

```
        var grid = new MongoGridFS(new MongoServer(new MongoServerSettings {Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, port)}), databaseName, new MongoGridFSSettings());
        grid.Upload(file.InputStream, file.FileName, new MongoGridFSCreateOptions
        {
            Id = imageId,
            ContentType = file.ContentType
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I did find something I thought would solve my problem, the class MongoGridFS. My problem now is that it takes a MongoServer, as it's first arg and times out when I give it a new instance or complains about a connectionstring not found.

```
var grid = new MongoGridFS(new MongoServer(new MongoServerSettings { Server = new MongoServerAddress(Settings.Default.WizdooMongoConnectionString) }), Settings.Default.WizdooMongoDatabaseName, new MongoGridFSSettings());
        grid.Upload(file.InputStream, file.FileName, new MongoGridFSCreateOptions
        {
            Id = imageId,
            ContentType = file.ContentType
        });
//Yealds: The settings property 'ConnectionString' was not found.
```

I suppose I need to give it a connectionstring, but I've been able to do CRUD fine in MongoDB without it. So weird for this service to require it all of a sudden. Maybe you can make it work for you though. I'm going to look in to it more when I have time... should work with correct config. If you get it to work pls give me a hint! Good luck! :)